# Edit and execute user input python code in Kivy - how to sandbox?

Tags: python, sandbox, kivy

In a Kivy app, I would like to be able to be able to have a multi-line text box in Kivy,
where the user can type/ edit python code.

Upon a user action, I would like to be able to run that code, to get the return value of a function with a known name. Of course, when doing so, the code has to be sand boxed to prevent the user from accessing anything else related to the app or the device it is running on.

Is there a recommended way of doing this? I have come across [Restricted Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython/), and am wondering if this is sufficient for a Kivy app, or if there are any alternative approaches that might suit it better.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have found Restricted Python (which works only for Python 2.7), you probably already know about `exec` and [disallow access to filesystem inside exec and eval in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104356/disallow-access-to-filesystem-inside-exec-and-eval-in-pytho) (which indicates that really sandboxing python is not possible -- you can make it challenging or help prevent mistake but you can't prevent mischief). RestrictedPython does not seem to support Python 3.x, so you should find out by emailing its developers if it is still maintained because kivy will eventually drop 2.7. Depending on what you want to allow, the `ast.literal_eval` may be adequate but it gives access to only very limited subset of python, I doubt it will be of use, maybe if your kivy app is a math application where the user can enter arithmetic expressions but beyond that, may not be sufficient.